# Add and remove value from array on click

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a Ul li list like

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <a>item first <a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>item first <a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>item first <a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>item first <a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to select the text of the anchor tag and add or remove on click with jquery.

```
var arr = [];

$(ul a).on('click',function(){
     arr.push($(this).text());
})
```

If again click then check if value is exist then remove from array. if not then add

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? The code you've posted can't be a serious try.

Comment: I have just posted an example not working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(ul a).on('click',function(){
   let currentElement=$(this).text().trim();
let foundElement = arr.some(function (element) {
    return element==currentElement;
  });
    if(!foundElement)
      {
        arr.push(currentElement);
      } 
    else 
    {
     arr.pop(currentElement);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first i would like to point out the missing quotes in `$(ul a)`. It should be `$('ul a')` with quotes. Then the strategy will be to find the text exist or not in the array which can be achieved like this:

```js
var arr = [];
$('ul a').on('click',function(){
    // use trim so that the spaces before and after do not affect
    var clickedText = $(this).text().trim();
    // the clicked anchor text exist
    if(arr.indexOf(clickedText) !== -1){
       // remove that text from array
       arr.splice(arr.indexOf(clickedText), 1);
    } else {
       arr.push(clickedText);
    }
     console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li>
       <a>item first <a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>item first <a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>item first <a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>item first <a>
   </li>
```